# Pandas - replace % signs in data and put them back

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
Name   Jan_2018   Feb_2018  Mar_2018
A      33%        40%       42%
B      20%        35%       50%
C      21%        31%       12%
```

I'm doing some operations with the numeric data (sums, averages, etc) so I need to remove the % sign so pandas can stop treating them as strings. However my output needs to have the % signs back.

Additionally I can't hardcode any columns since more may get added in the future.

**What's the easiest way to remove the % signs from the numeric data and add them back again later?**

Comment: `df.replace({'%':'', regex=True)` and to add back `df.astype(str).add('%')`. Might want to `pd.to_numeric` in the middle to make columns `int` dtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
df = df.replace({'%':''}, regex=True)

    Name    Jan_2018    Feb_2018    Mar_2018
0   A       33          40          42
1   B       20          35          50
2   C       21          31          12
```

Convert to numbers

```
df = df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='ignore'))

df.dtypes
Name        object
Jan_2018     int64
Feb_2018     int64
Mar_2018     int64
dtype: object
```

Convert back to `%` only numeric columns

```
mask = df.dtypes[[np.issubdtype(x, np.number) for x in df.dtypes]].index
df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].astype(str).add('%')

    Name    Jan_2018    Feb_2018    Mar_2018
0   A       33%         40%         42%
1   B       20%         35%         50%
2   C       21%         31%         12%
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `%`

```
df=df.apply(lambda x : x.str.rstrip('%'))
df
#df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')

Out[156]: 
  Name Jan_2018 Feb_2018 Mar_2018
0    A       33       40       42
1    B       20       35       50
2    C       21       31       12
```

Add it back

```
#df.iloc[:,1:]=df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str)
df.iloc[:,1:]+='%'
df
Out[160]: 
  Name Jan_2018 Feb_2018 Mar_2018
0    A      33%      40%      42%
1    B      20%      35%      50%
2    C      21%      31%      12%
```

Comment: Name isn't necessarily going to be the only non-numeric column.

Comment: @JesusMonroe what you mean ?

Comment: There could be more columns added as the table I read from is updated. The numeric data will always be %'s but if they added a column like 'unique_code' or something, your solution would add a % to every entry in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `%` from pandas dataframe.

```
df.replace({'%': ''}, regex=True)
```

Or if you want to replace a specific column then :

```
df['some_col'].replace({'%': ''}, regex=True)

df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].replace({'%':''}, regex=True)
```

The str attribute per [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)

```
df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].str.replace('%', '')
```

**another good example altogether ignoring symbols and select only numeric values with pandas:**

Use str.strip if the prefix is fixed or str.replace if not:

```
data = pandas.Series(["U$ 192.0"])
data.str.replace('^[^\d]*', '').astype(float)
```

This removes all the non-numeric characters to the left of the number, and casts to float.